# Is qHash consistent across computers?

Tags: string, qt, database-design, hash, primary-key

I have a database table with multiple text columns that collectively have to be unique, and I don't want to use a multicolumn key, so I was thinking to hash the strings together into an int and use that as the primary key. I was wondering if it would be a better idea to take advantage of [uint qHash ( const QString & key )](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qhash.html#qHash-16), or to write my own function, given that the database will need to be edited by different people in different places. (Also, if the whole approach is bad, please help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qHash is implemented as below :

```
static uint hash(const uchar *p, int n)
{
    uint h = 0;
    uint g;

    while (n--) {
        h = (h << 4) + *p++;
        if ((g = (h & 0xf0000000)) != 0)
            h ^= g >> 23;
        h &= ~g;
    }
    return h;
}

static uint hash(const QChar *p, int n)
{
    uint h = 0;
    uint g;

    while (n--) {
        h = (h << 4) + (*p++).unicode();
        if ((g = (h & 0xf0000000)) != 0)
            h ^= g >> 23;
        h &= ~g;
    }
    return h;
}
```

There is nothing specific to platform in that code. However a hash algorithm does not guarantee uniqueness like a database. It does its best to avoid collisions but it is not guaranteed. That is why most hash containers use buckets and reallocation algorithms.